# Pandas Dataframe filtering and count on the result of an aggregation

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count, where-clause, aggregation

I try to filter and count the result of an aggregation:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[2],[3],[2]],columns=['A'])
print(df)

   A 
 0 2 
 1 3 
 2 2

dfCount = df.groupby(['A']).agg({'A':['count']}).reset_index(drop=True) 
print(dfCount)

  count 
A 
2 2 
3 1

result = dfCount.where(dfCount.count == 1).count()
```

I simply want the number of expressions which are just one time in the original dataset.
In this case I want result to be 1.

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you should using `value_counts`

```
df.A.value_counts().eq(1).sum()
Out[416]: 1
```

Comment: Great, that was pretty fast! 
I already checked that .ge(2) (>=2) and .le(5) (<=5) works as well.
But .ge(2).le(10) gives me 2 and not 1.
May you tell me what I need to write for >=2 and <=5?

Comment: @t.c.r `ge` =`>=`

Comment: Got it as well: .between(2, 5)